# Recursive function removing all instances of a character in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I wrote a recursive to remove nodes with a specific data value, however it is not working correctly.

```
Node * removeAll(Node *top, char c){
    if(top == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Node *newTop;
    if(top->data == c){
        newTop = top->next;
        delete top;
    }else{
        newTop = top;
    }

    newTop->next = removeAll(newTop->next,c);

    return newTop;
}
```

The linked list provided to the function contains the values `h e l l o`
I expected the outputted list to contain the values `h e o`, but instead it has the values `h e l o`

Comment: seems like a good opportunity to use a debugger

Comment: Why use recursion when a simple iterative loop would suffice? And that would also avoid any risk of a stack overflow when looping through large lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(top->data == c){
    newTop = top->next;
    delete top;
}else{
    newTop = top;
}
```

to this:

```
while(top && top->data == c){
    newTop = top->next;
    delete top;
    top = newTop;
}
newTop = top;
```

That way successive elements which contain the target value will all be deleted before moving to the next element.

As an aside, this function might use less memory and be faster if it were written iteratively rather than recursively.

Comment: ``newTop = top->next" should be "top = top->next", but otherwise this works, i appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer this as a tutorial because nearly everyone struggles a bit when learning how to think recursively.

Note that because it uses a `while` loop, @Edward's answer isn't a fully recursive form.

When you're learning, it invariably helps to write out a recursive description *of the answer* in human language first.  Starting with code draws focus away from thinking about the algorithm and toward unimportant details like syntax and pointer semantics. In English,

> A list of the form `[HEAD, rest_of_list]` with character C removed is equal to  `rest_of_list` with character C removed and `HEAD` optionally pre-pended to it. Whether to prepend `HEAD` or not depends on whether it's equal to `C`.

Here `HEAD` is a single character, and `rest_of_list` is itself a list.

The recursive part is removing `C` from `rest_of_list`. Note that the recursion is occurring on a string one character shorter than the input. That's good! It means that the algorithm is making progress from one recursive call to the next.

We'll also need to describe a "base case" where the recursion stops. Here since the list is getting shorter from one call to the next, it's logical to try the empty list. In English,

> When the input list is empty, it can't contain `C`, so return the empty list.

So we're ready to write code.  First the base case. Your implementation is fine. A `NULL` pointer is the empty list in the usual C list implementation.

```
Node *removeAll(Node *list, char c) {
  // Base case.
  if (list == NULL) return NULL;
  // Recursive case.
  // TODO: Complete me.
}
```

For the recursive case, `HEAD` as we wrote in English is `list->data` in C. And `rest_of_list` is `list->next`.  So go ahead and write that:

```
  // Recursive case.
  char head = list->data;
  Node *rest = list->next;
```

The recursive case itself has 2 cases. If `head` is `c`, then we just return `rest` with `c` removed.

```
  if (c == head) return removeAll(rest, c);
```

The remaining case is where `head` *is not* equal to `c`. Here there's a choice. You need a node to hold `c`.  You can either re-use the one that currently holds it, which means you're changing the original list.  Or you can allocate a new node, which means the original list remains intact. In real applications, this decision can be extremely important. Let's say you want to keep the original list intact. Prepending is accomplished with

```
return allocateNewNode(head, removeAll(rest, c));
```

Here `allocateNewNode` gets fresh memory for the node that's not being used for some other list. For example, it could call `malloc`.

On the other hand, if you want to change the input list (the term `mutate` is pretty common), then modify the first node in `list`.

```
list->next = removeAll(rest, c);
return list;
```

All together, the mutating case is:

```
Node *removeAll(Node *list, char c) {
  // Base case: on empty list, return empty list.
  if (list == NULL) return NULL;
  // Recursive cases. Extract head value and rest of list.
  char head = list->data;
  Node *rest = list->next;
  // If head is C, return rest with C removed.
  if (c == head) return removeAll(rest, c);
  // Otherwise prepend C to rest with C removed by mutating the first list node, 
  // which already contains head.
  list->next = removeAll(rest, c);
  return list;
}
```

I hope this is helpful to you and others trying to get the hang of recursive thinking.